# error in running spring application on ubuntu

Tags: spring, ubuntu

I create a runnable jar from a spring project in windows when I run it with this command:

```
 java -jar springjar.jar
```

It's run and works fine.
But in Ubuntu when I run the same jar I get this error

[error link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rnax_ee-5UKI3v167ixZv1Bsx3ZmZbuDQtZ2CnJ38Qs/edit?usp=sharing)

thanks for any help.

Comment: What Java version you are using?

Comment: openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17